# Autodesk Forge Viewer - setprofile just shows black model

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Why by using setprofile shows just Black model (light changed?)

exp as default:

```
const defaultProfile = viewer.profileManager.getProfileOrDefault();
viewer.setProfile(defaultProfile);
```

or as json:

```
const profileSettings = {
            extensions: {
                load: ["Autodesk.BimWalk"],   // Extensions to load
                unload: ["Autodesk.ViewCubeUi"]  // Extensions to unload and to not load
            }
        }
const profile = new Autodesk.Viewing.Profile(profileSettings);
viewer.setProfile(profile);
```

[PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx0MY.png)

Comment: Is it reproducible all the time? With a specific model or all of them you've tried? Can you upload the offending model to an online drive and drop the link to forge.help@autodesk.com to help us look into the issue as I was unable to reproduce this using my own model?

Comment: I have tested on all models, exp:  [rst_basic_sample_project.rvt](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/de/support/revit-products/getting-started/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/DEU/Revit-GetStarted/files/GUID-61EF2F22-3A1F-4317-B925-1E85F138BE88-htm.html) model

Comment: Thanks and can confirm to be able to reproduce the issue (with the revit house model but not the other ones) ... working with Engineering on this (LMV-5473) and will get back with progress soon...

Comment: I've been trying to repro the issue with the exact same Revit file and the same profile JSON (in viewer version 7.27), but with no luck. Could you check with this viewer version as well? And could you provide more info please? For example, when exactly are you setting the profile?